# How to make the smartphone work as a PC monitor?

Tags: screen, windows

I am have a pc and recently my dell monitor stopped working so i had called up the customer careband they said that they will get it replaced within a week. So till that time i can't use the pc so is there any way to use my rooted android phone (running 4.3, jelly bean) as a temporary monitor as my pc is working perfect but i have no display. Note that i can't install any softwares on the pc as i don't have a display. I only have a phone, wifi network and usb option. Is there any way that i can achieve this without installing any software on the pc just using the phone and installing some app on the phone? I hope for a good response

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without installing any software on the PC.

Comment: Does your PC feature an HDMI port?

Comment: @Izzy no it doesn't have an hdmi port

Comment: Afraid then I'll have to stick with Dan, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy Is there any hacking method to force the pc mirror the display

Comment: This has become a PC related question, so I'm flagging to close this as off-topic. Maybe you should have better luck on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: I agree with @TamoghnaChowdhury on the PC part: check that on SU, as suggested. If you then need help on the Android side, be welcome back here ([edit] your question then accordingly). When asking at SU, make sure to include the OS used on the PC.